# The phrase: "Find out more information about it at . . . "

Tags: idioms, dialects

I hear this on local radio in northwestern Pennsylvania.

"You can find out more information about it at ..."

This grates on me a bit.  I expect "Find out more at . . . "  or "Find more information about it at. . . "

The phase I often hear seems to be a strange combination of the two I find acceptable.

Am I wrong in thinking that this is unusual if not incorrect usage?
Is it a regional dialect thing of is it widespread?

Comment: If it's the same thing all the time, I can well understand why it grates. Why don't you drop them a line, suggesting they vary their format, such as with "Discover more about it at..."; "Learn more about it at...", "Find the details at..." etc.

Comment: If I heard you say, "Find out more at ..." and I asked you, "Find out more *what*?" What would you tell me?

Comment: Unfortunately, I hear it on more that one radio station and on television as well.  That is why I wondered whether it is regional or widespread.  It seems not to be a single person's error.

Comment: @Jim  Thank you, that's a good point.  But what other more is there that one could find out?

Comment: What do you think the error is exactly?The fact that they said "information" as well as "find out"?

Comment: It rubs me the wrong way, too, when I hear that, unless the primary purpose of a store visit is to gather information. I don't think such ads are really effective.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that the offending locution comes at the end of a discussion or at least a mention of something so the topic is already understood by most hearers. But the pronoun "it" will not be helpful for someone just tuning in.

More importantly, I agree that the locution is a barbarism although it may not be realistic to expect careful speech from live radio or television.

"Find out" implies "hunt for," and the whole point of the locution is to obviate the need for people to go hunting for additional information. So I would choose "Find more information about X at Y" as quick, simple, and exact.

Comment: ... a "barbarism"?

Comment: an idea, act, or expression that in form or use offends against contemporary standards of good taste or acceptability

Comment: What on earth offend contemporary standards of good taste here??

Comment: The whole point of the OP is that that "find out more information about" offends against good taste in American usage of English. "Find out more about something" or "find out more information about" do not. Of course, taste is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I don't see what's offensive.